# remove() function undefined in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I run my page on Chrome everything works fine but when I run on IE11 I cannot find the `remove()` function.

```js
function restartAnimatorSelf() {
  var el = $('#selfLabel'),
    newone = el.clone(true);

  el.before(newone);
  var child = $("#popSelf").children()[1];
  $("#popSelf").children()[1].remove();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're accessing the jQuery object by index which is returning an Element object, not a jQuery object. As such you're calling the native JS [`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Browser_compatibility) method, not the jQuery one, which is unsupported in IE.

To fix this, use `eq()` to retrieve the element by index:

```
var $child = $("#popSelf").children().eq(1);
$child.remove();
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for the explanation!